# C++ std::vector.data not found by MinGW

Tags: c++, mingw

I have been able to use OpenGL's glVertexPointer function using the following C++ code:

```
glVertexPointer(3, GL_DOUBLE, 0, myMeasuredPoints.data());
```

myMeasuredPoints is a C++ vector with elements of type double. When compiling this code with Visual C++, there is no problem at all. However, when using MinGW to compile, I get the following error:

```
error: 'class std::vector<double, std::allocator<double>' has no member named 'data'
```

Strangely, I do not get this error any other place in the code where I invoke functions such as myMeasuredPoints.push_back() to push values onto the vector. These other instances have all been before using the .data() function, so it hasn't simply been a case of the code crashing before reaching the other instances.

Any thoughts?

Comment: If you do need a newer version of MinGW, and are willing/able to update, I find this easy and useful: http://nuwen.net/mingw.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `data` function was added in C++11. Make sure you compile with `-std=c++0x` or `-std=c++11` and have a version of MinGW that includes the function.

If that's not possible, you can use the usual C++03 variant:

```
&myMeasuredPoints[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

If your compiler doesn't support C++11 then you can use

```
&myMeasuredPoints[0]
```